# Question regarding delegation of Viewmodel property(Android)(Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

Whenever I am trying to delegate my `viewmodel` using the `delegated property` in my `Fragments`

`val viewModel:NewsViewModel by activityViewModels<> {  }`

---

This is the `error` I would receive.

```
Property delegate must have a 'getValue(BreakingNews, KProperty*>)' method. None of the following functions are suitable.
    Lazy<NewsViewModel>.getValue(Any?, KProperty<*>)   
    where T = NewsViewModel for inline operator fun <T> Lazy<T>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: 
    KProperty<*>): T defined in kotlin
```

---

However, instantiating the `viewmodel` instance in the `MainActivity` this way, seems fine

```
val viewmodelFactory = ViewModelProviderFactory(dataRepo)
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,viewmodelFactory).get(NewsViewModel::class.java)
```

---

I assumed at first it may be due to the `viewmodelFactory` which is as follows.

```
class ViewModelProviderFactory(val Repo:NewsRepository): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>,extras: CreationExtras): T {

    return NewsViewModel(Repo) as T
}
}
```

---

The code below are the properties in my `ViewModel`, This is odd as I have cross-referred from multiple sources including the official `docs.

```
var breakingNews: MutableLiveData<Resource<ArticleList>> = MutableLiveData()

  var breakingNewsPage = 1
  var breakingNewsResponse: ArticleList? = null
  var searchNews: MutableLiveData<Resource<ArticleList>> = MutableLiveData()
  var searchNewsPage = 1
  var searchNewsResponse: ArticleList? = null
  var savedNumerics = 0

  var _status = MutableLiveData<String>()
  ....
    }
```

Comment: Try `val viewModel:NewsViewModel by activityViewModels()`.

Comment: The solution seems to have worked thanks! however, why can't I use the lambda expression instead? What is the error message trying to tell me and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you want just `val viewModel:NewsViewModel by activityViewModels()`.

In your case, with `val viewModel:NewsViewModel by activityViewModels<> {  }`, you skipped two things.

First, you are attempting to provide a value for the `extrasProducer` parameter to [the `activityViewModels()` function](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment).activityViewModels(kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0)). However, that lambda expression needs to evaluate to [a `CreationExtras` object](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/CreationExtras), and yours evaluates to `Unit`.

Second, you failed to provide a type. AFAIK, `<>` is not going to be valid syntax here. Either leave the `<>` off (and the compiler should infer the type from the property type) or fully qualify it as `<NewsViewModel>`. I think this is the cause of your specific syntax error, but even if you fix this, you should then run into a problem with your empty lambda expression.